# Build Nirgam using g++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to build the nirgam software using Debian in VMware environment. When I issue command make I end up in an error as given below.

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W1,-soname,application/lib/App_send.so’
make: *** [application/lib/App_send.so] Error 1
```

The snippets from the makefile is given below,

```
application/lib/%.so : application/src/%.o
    $(CC) -shared -W1,-soname,$@ -o $@ $<

router/lib/%.so : router/src/%.o
    $(CC) -shared -W1,-soname,$@ -o $@ $<
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You have copied the makefile wrong, the option is not `-W1` but `-Wl` with the letter `l` (lower-case `L`) and not the digit `1`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it after your suggestion and found to be compiling without any issues!!!